# How can I add a sub to define, what a a button will do, before the button is created?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a game, where I can add "soldiers" (which are buttons) by clicking a "summon soldier" button.
I already managed to create these buttons and also to summon them always at a new position, but I want to add a sub or something like that, where I can define, what is happening, when I press one of the "soldier" buttons, since I want them to move or attack.

I wanted to do it like this:

```
Private Sub btnsolider_Click(send As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles solider.Click

End Sub
```

but it is not working, because there currently is no button, who is called "soldier" (which makes sense)

So, this is the code, to create the "soldiers" buttons (I created x and y in the main method):

```
Private Sub btnSummonSolider_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSummonSolider.Click

        'going to use this later, to numerise the soldiers
        solidersamount = solidersamount + 1

        'create new soldiers at next position
        Dim solider As New Button
        solider.Text = "Solider"
        solider.BackColor = Color.Red
        solider.Location = New Point(x, y)
        solider.Height = 95
        solider.Width = 95
        solider.BringToFront()
        Fieldstoback()
        Me.Controls.Add(solider)

        'changes the new summoning position to the next spot
        If x = 910 Then
            x = 10
            y = y + 100
        Else x = x + 100
        End If

    End Sub
```

I also created a 10*10 area of buttons I the background, which I want to use as grid, where I can move the soldiers and other units, build bases on etc...
When I press the solider button, I want it to highlight the background/grid buttons in the background, to show, where the solider can move (plus show, where some obstacles are, he can't cross)

So you see, it is relatively senseless, to write this in the sub of the "SummonSoldier" button, so I need a extra sup for the solider (I just need one, since every solider button have to do the same, but if I want to add heal points/life points or the current position for the movement, I need to clone the sub somehow)

Here also a picture, so you can imagine a bit more, how it looks like, right now:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/556601185264599051/560466425211518976/solidergame.PNG

I know, this stuff seems a bit complicated, but I would appreciate your help, thank you

Comment: I think what you want is to attach the Sub Routine btnSoldeier_Click() to each soldier as they spawn by attaching the sub to their Click event. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-create-event-handlers-at-run-time-for-windows-forms), so something like this in your `btnSummonSoldier` should work: `AddHandler solider.Click, AddressOf btnsolider_Click`

Comment: *And*... please be sure to remove the handlers as well; `RemoveHandler solider.Click, AddressOf btnsolider_Click`...

Comment: Okay thank you, i will try this out.
And i just realised, that i wrote the word soldier wrong, the entire time, in the whole code and in my question, jesus i must have been tired, how did that happend ?
So, thanks for your answer, it showed me a way of solving my problem and it let me realise my wrong spelling xD